# How to convert 2 forEach loops into functional code?

Tags: java, functional-programming

How to convert the following nested forEach loop into functional code?

```
ABC abc = new ABC();

for (A a : aList) {
    for (String b : bList) {
        if (Objects.equals(a.getName(), b)) {
            abc.setId(a.getId());
            abc.setValue(a.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to convert it this way, but it didn't work:

```
aList.forEach(a -> {
    bList.stream()
         .filter(b -> Objects.equals(b, a.getName()));

    abc.setId(a.getId());
    abc.setValue(a.getValue());
});
```

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you want to traverse the array until `a.getName()` equals `b` ,then exit?

Comment: if `a.getName()` equals `b`, then I want to set `abc.setId()` and `abc.setValue();`

Comment: assuming `bList` is a `List`, would be easier to use `bList.contains(a.getName())` instead of inner loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
aList.forEach(a -> {
    if( bList.stream()
         .anyMatch(b -> Objects.equals(b, a.getName()))){

       abc.setId(a.getId());
       abc.setValue(a.getValue());
    }
});
```

or better

```
aList.stream().filter(a -> bList.stream()
                                .anyMatch(b -> Objects.equals(b,a.getName())))
              .findAny()
              .ifPresent(a -> {
                  abc.setId(a.getId());
                  abc.setValue(a.getValue());
               });
```

Comment: While this is technically correct, I can't imagine the use in writing such convoluted code just because the data structures aren't fit for the use case. Working with lists here is just bad design.

Comment: What exactly convoluted about this code?

Comment: Well it's longer than the one using `for` and just as inefficient. Can you explain to me the advantage of using this version of the code? I don't find it very pretty, and while it's functional, that isn't enough to make me happy.

Comment: It is easier to understand. Steps of the process not mixed. First you look for value you need, then you use that value to adjust `abc`. In `for` version you need to decipher that two loops are actually lookup.

Comment: Easier to understand is debatable. I consider the nested for-loops a common idiom, but also a clear indicator that there's quadratic complexity, and maybe there should be different design rather than `for` vs. `stream`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what is considered a "functional code" and why that is needed here.
My approach, assuming `bList` is a `List<String>`:

```java
var abc = aList
          .stream()
          .filter(this::isKnownName)
          .map(this::abcFromA)
          .findFirst()    // see ¹ bellow 
          .orElseGet(ABC::new);
```

using the following helper *functions* - not really needed, we could use lambda expressions, but I think using this is a little bit more readable **²** :

```java
private boolean isKnownName(A a) {
    return bList.contains(a.getName());
}
    
private ABC abcFromA(A a) {
    var result = new ABC();
    result.setId(a.getId());
    result.setValue(a.getValue());
    return result;
}
```

---

**¹** this code is using the first match found in `bList`, code in question is using the last match

**²** I would struggle between using this solution at all and using a single loop (with `bList.contains()` instead of inner loop as posted in question).